# SAS/ACCESS ODBC Oracle, Greek characters are displayed as question marks (?)

Tags: oracle, sas, odbc

We installed oracle instant client v19 to connect to oracle dbs via ODBC, but when we read data all Greek characters showing up as question marks.

Comment: Check your character set settings - e.g. NLS_LANG.

Comment: NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET AL16UTF16
NLS_CHARACTERSET EL8ISO8859P7

Comment: OK, but on the client PC/SAS/Access side - not sure what that relies on, but do you have NLS_LANG set? [This might be helpful](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-nls-lang.html). Or you could need to set the character set within SAS/Access, I'm not sure...

Comment: The prefix `EL` -> `Ellada` already stands for representing `Greece`